# extra columns with Sequelize many to many

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to know how can I get the extra columns from my linker table.

Currently I have 3 tables :

```
Courses : id, title, description,
Sections: id, title, description,
CoursesSections : id, fk_course_id, fk_section_id, position
```

I try to get the courses with this, but I don't understand how can I get "position" from my linker table :

```
db.Course.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 1,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Section,
            as: "Section",
            through: {
                attributes: ["position"],
            },
        },
    ],
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("position"), "ASC"]],
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.dataValues.position) // <= undefined
    console.log(response.dataValues.Section.position) // <= <= undefined
    return response.dataValues.Section // <= get without "position" field
})
```

> Course model :

```
Course.associate = (models) => {
    models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Section, {
        as: "Section",
        through: "CourseSection",
        foreignKey: "fk_course_id",
        otherKey: "fk_section_id",
    })
}
```

> Section model :

```
Section.associate = (models) => {
    models.Section.belongsToMany(models.Course, {
        as: "Course",
        through: "CourseSection",
        foreignKey: "fk_section_id",
        otherKey: "fk_course_id",
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CourseSection model :

```
CourseSection.associate = (models) => {
    models.CourseSection.belongsToMany(models.Course, {
        through: "CoursesSections",
        foreignKey: "fk_course_id",
    })
    models.CourseSection.belongsToMany(models.Section, {
        through: "CoursesSections",
        foreignKey: "fk_section_id",
    })
}
```

Associate CourseSection with Course and Section like this:

```
Course.associate = (models) => {
    models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Section, {
        as: "Section",
        through: models.CourseSection,
        foreignKey: "fk_course_id",
        otherKey: "fk_section_id",
    })
}

Section.associate = (models) => {
    models.Section.belongsToMany(models.Course, {
        as: "Course",
        through: models.CourseSection,
        foreignKey: "fk_section_id",
        otherKey: "fk_course_id",
    })
}
```

Get position field with this :

```
const course = await db.Course.findOne({
    where: {
        id: parent.dataValues.id,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Section,
            as: "Section",
            through: {
                attributes: ["position"],
            },
        },
    ],
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("position"), "ASC"]],
})

course.Section.forEach((section) => {
    console.log(section.dataValues.coursessections.position)

    section.position = section.dataValues.coursessections.position
})

return course.dataValues.Section
```

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly ! I updated your post with some modifications !